# Picklist Dependent fields -- the dependent field I want is not available

Tags: field-dependencies

I have, on a contract object, two fields. One is a service frequency, and one is billing. They are very similar, except I want to make a dependency so that if the service frequency is quarterly, let's say, the billing frequency cannot be monthly or weekly. Essentially, I want it to be at most as frequent as the services.

I want the controlling field to be service frequency, but when I select it, I cannot choose billing frequency as an option. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there are a few cases where a picklist cannot be a `dependent` field.

1. Standard picklist fields cannot be `dependent` fields
2. If a picklist is already a `dependent` field to some other picklist, you can't make it a `dependent` field again
3. You cannot make a circular dependency between two or more fields (e.g. - A controls B, B controls C, C **cannot control** neither A or B as that would make a circular dependency).

I suggest you check the 2nd case if the field doesn't even appear as an option for `dependent field`.